# Show Bitmap into UI thread with IndoorAtlas

Tags: android, indoor-positioning-system

Here is what i want supposed to be : load floorplan in IndoorAtlas and show current location.
Here is my code :

```
public void loadFloorPlanImage(FloorPlan floorPlan) {
    BitmapFactory.Options options = createBitmapOptions(floorPlan);
    FutureResult<Bitmap> result = mIndoorAtlas.fetchFloorPlanImage(floorPlan,options);
    result.setCallback(new ResultCallback<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(final Bitmap result) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
                }
        });
        }
    });
}
```

And this :

```
private BitmapFactory.Options createBitmapOptions(FloorPlan floorPlan) {
    int reqWidth = 2048;
    int reqHeight = 2048;
    final int width = (int) floorPlan.dimensions[0];
    final int height = (int) floorPlan.dimensions[1];
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }
    options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;
    return options;
}
```

I received error result :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.graphics.BitmapFactory$Options.inSampleSize' on a null object reference
        at skripsi.ubm.studenttracking.indoor.createBitmapOptions(indoor.java:370)
        at skripsi.ubm.studenttracking.indoor.loadFloorPlanImage(indoor.java:322)
        at skripsi.ubm.studenttracking.indoor$1.onResult(indoor.java:163)
        at skripsi.ubm.studenttracking.indoor$1.onResult(indoor.java:159)
```

Could you help me ?

Comment: You forgot to initialize options inside createBitmapOptions method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize like this:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options = createBitmapOptions(floorPlan);
```

Comment: It still remain the same. The problem is : 'Attempt to write to field 'int android.graphics.BitmapFactory$Options.inSampleSize' on a null object reference.

Comment: sry...I was wrong...you should initialize options in method createBitmapOptions by adding : `BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();`